# PHP search for keyword match in url

Tags: php

Hi ,
I have a list of keywords which I need to search on the url to see if there's any match.

```
$keyword ='keyword1|keyword2|keyword3';
```

`$url` could be

```
$url = "www.keyword1castle.com";
```

if there is a match just echo something

How could I do this?

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=php+match+words+in+string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

- explode your keyword string with `|` as the delimiter
- loop through the array
- check if the URL contains the string using `strpos()` (or `stripos()` if you want a case-insensitive check)
- if it does, break out of the loop
- if it doesn't, repeat the process

Code:

```
$keyword ='keyword1|keyword2|keyword3';
$url = "www.keyword1castle.com";

$parts = explode('|', $keyword);

foreach ($parts as $part) {
    if(strpos($url, $part) !== FALSE) {
        echo "keyword found in URL\n";
        break;
    }
    else {
        echo "keyword not found\n";
    }
}
```

Documentation: [**`explode()`**](http://php.net/explode), [**`strpos()`**](http://php.net/strpos)

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/BvHH5L17)

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/stripos

```
$found = false;
foreach (explode('|', $keyword) AS $val) {
    $found = stripos($url, $val);
    if ($found !== false) {
       break;
    }
}

if ($found !== false) {
   echo "string found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strpos` : [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
if (false !== strpos($url, 'keyword1')) {
   echo "keyword1 found";
}
```

Comment: `strpos` never returns `-1`; it has a positive integer or `false` + you are missing a bracket.

Comment: @DanFromGermany : thanks, I wrote too fast and I didn't read back :s. I have correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$keyword ='keyword1';
$url = "www.keyword1castle.com";
if (strpos($url,$keyword) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```